# set_metadata_recursive failing on Android install

Tags: android, installation, rom, selinux

I'm trying to bring up a 4.4 android build for my droid razr HD. It compiles cleanly, but when I try to install it fails with the following error in the recovery log:

```
    ApplyParsedPerms: removexattr of /system/xbin/zipalign to 0 failed: Operation not supported on transport endpoint      
script aborted: set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed                                                            
set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed                                                                            
E:Error executing updater binary in zip '/external_sd/MSI/update-XenonHD-11-07-13-signed-xt926.zip'                    
Error flashing zip '/external_sd/MSI/update-XenonHD-11-07-13-signed-xt926.zip'
```

So... I did a fair amount of research into the changes made by AOSP in build and bootable/recovery, including comments others have made on this issue, and I'm thinking it's a missing seandroid configuration for /system/xbin. It's definitely something about items in /system/xbin because when I remove zipalign from the build, it errors out on tcpdump, and so on..
Is this indeed a sepolicy configuration that's missing? Is there something else I need to check? 
Can anyone tell me how to include xbin without having to mess with the files residing there?
Thanks, appreciate your time!

Comment: Belongs on Android.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 17):

I fixed this issue on my Nexus 7 (2012) by upgrading to the latest ClockworkMod Recovery from http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager.

Comment: This worked for me even when updating my Nexus 4 to Android 4.4. The problem seems to come from an incomplete/bugged implementation of the `set_metadata_recursive` function in previous CWM versions, which is used in Google's new update scripts instead of the old `set_perms_recursive` function.

Comment: upgrade clockwork to 6.0.4.3 then go to install zip will be just fine.

Answer (score 4):

In short, if you want to flash KitKat Android 4.4, you'll have to upgrade to a version of CWM greater than v6.0.4.5. Or, use an alternate bootloader.

Comment: For HTC desire HD for example, I had to install the PhilZ_Touch_Recovery_6.40.7_ace.img and then CM11 install worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The correct command for flashing, in response to @Blue_On_It:

```
fastboot flash recovery clockworkmod.img
```

Answer (score 1):

1.- Start the mobile in recovery mode

2.- You must open adb console (after download the newest version of ClockWorkMod) and write "fastboot recovery clockworkmod.img" (you have the fastboot executable in the platform-tools folder)

3.- While the console write: "Waiting the mobile" or similar you restart the mobile.
The ClockWorkMod recovery new version will be installed.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade you ClockworkMod Recovery to 6.0.4.5, you can download the file [here](http://raspisimon.no-ip.org/download_ws.php?file=GT-P3100_ClockworkMod-Recovery_6.0.4.5_Non-Touch-UNOFFICIAL.zip.html) and read the tutorial how to upgrade [here](http://raspisimon.no-ip.org/kitkat.php) and if you stuck into boot and can not go to inside the device/ No OS please read [here](http://highonandroid.com/android-roms/how-to-copy-files-over-to-your-android-in-a-bootloop-with-no-os-using-adb/) the tutorial and watch video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaK5OxUeDKM) how to Copy Files Over to your Android with ADB

Hope that help you...:)